# What .NET runtime version do I select in Azure Web Apps for a .NET Framework 4.6.1 web forms app?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-webapps

I'm working on an ASP.NET web forms application with `targetFramework="net461"`

I want to deploy this to Azure Web Apps but they only offer the following:

- .NET 7
- .NET 6
- ASP.NET V4.8
- ASP.NET V3.5

4.6.1 is part of the .NET Framework family, but it is a web forms application so it is an ASP.NET application, correct??

So should I choose ASP.NET V3.5? Or V4.8? Or can I not upload my web forms application in its current state at all?

Comment: According to [What is Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms): _ASP.NET Web Forms is a part of the ASP.NET web application framework and is included with Visual Studio. It is one of the four programming models you can use to create ASP.NET web applications, the others are ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web Pages, and ASP.NET Single Page Applications...Built on the Microsoft .NET Framework._

Comment: If you're currently using _targetFramework="net461"_ then why would you choose v3.5? Would v3.5 have the features available in 4.0+? If you're favorite beverage costs $4.62 and you only have $3.50, can you buy it? Alternatively, if your favorite beverage costs $4.62 and you have $4.80 can you buy it?

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid You just explained in one comment what I couldnt understand in an hour of googling... Thank you for taking the time to write that out....So to answer your Q...yes thats why I was choosing ASP.NET V3.5 for my net461 because as you said I have more, but I dont have enough to go to ASP.NET V4.8?? Isnt that correct? but that doesnt make sense with the first part of your Q... 'If you're currently using targetFramework="net461" then why would you choose v3.5?' no it wont have the features available in 4.0+ but I only have v3.5 or v4.8 to choose from?

Comment: You application written using _net461_ is the _product_ you're attempting to purchase which means you'd need v4.8. Perhaps you didn't notice what I did with the dollar amounts in the comments above.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see I see… now I get it. Yes very clever. I need 4.8 to run 461.. I was looking at it the other way around. I thought I have 461 but don’t have enough to get to 4.8 so have to downgrade. Two explanations in one day lol… thank you…@Tudeschizieuinchid if you want to write up any answer to read our comments I’ll gladly award the answers again thank you

Comment: If you have the budget, I'd try and consider upgrading the app to the latest or at least to the latest LTS of .Net.

Answer (score -2):

The list you included is a set of options where each one is a distinct *major version* of the platform. The version number after it is the specific version, but all major versions of .NET are installed side-by-side rather than on top of existing major versions (e.g., you can have .NET 1, .NET 2, .NET 3, and .NET 4 all installed on an environment at the same time).

Each major version of .NET includes backward-compatibility within that version (e.g. an environment with .NET 4.8 installed can run anything from 4.0 to 4.8). This is the standard practice for most applications or frameworks that follow this semantic versioning scheme (the `major.minor.patch` versioning scheme); requiring an application to be *rebuilt* for a new framework version would mandate a "major change", thus calling for a "major version" increment (e.g. from 3.x to 4.0).

Microsoft unified the .NET families (.NET Framework and .NET Core) in version 5 based on the .NET Core architecture; it is entirely incompatible with .NET Framework, so you are correct that .NET 6 or .NET 7 would be the wrong choices. Your web forms app simply won't work at all; it would be like trying to insert a cassette tape into a CD player slot.

Likewise, trying to run your .NET 4.6.1 app in a .NET 3.5 environment won't work, either. It's a much closer match, but .NET 4.x apps use things that aren't supported by .NET 3.x; the analogy here might be like trying to insert a DVD into a CD player slot. It'll *fit*, but it won't play.

Because of this, you should select the .NET 4.8 environment to run any .NET 4.x.x web forms.